# With CAS single-sign on, how to auto-login after sign up?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I'm using CAS for single sign on (the server runs rbCAS / Casino). One of the client applications serves as the place where a user signs up for a new account. I'll call this the client app.

Prior to using CAS, when a user signed up successfully in the client app, we would automatically log her in to the client app by setting the necessary session data, etc.

With CAS, however, there doesn't seem to be any way to automatically log the user in. Instead, we have to redirect them immediately to a login form on the CAS application. This is awkward and not very user-friendly. (They've just selected a username and password, paid their money, etc. It's silly to ask them to re-enter their account credentials 5 seconds later.)

To be clear: it would be possible to register the login session in the client app alone, but the CAS server wouldn't know about the login and therefore single sign on would not work if the user subsequently visited another client application.

Is there any way around this problem? I thought about perhaps loading the CAS login form in a 1px iframe and using javascript to submit it, but that seems hacky and insecure.